# Checking a condition at a pd.DataFrame with np.where() and apply a function to more than one columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Assume a dataframe df and two columns within it each one hosting respectively a value for mass and the unit of measurement. The two columns will look like this:

```
df.head()
    Mass  Unit
0     14     g
1   1.57    kg
2    701     g
3  0.003    tn
4    0.6    kg
```

I want to have a consistent system of measurements and thus, I perform the following:

```
df['Mass']=np.where(df['Unit']=='g', df['Mass']/1000, df['Mass'])  #1
df['Unit']=np.where(df['Unit']=='g', 'kg', df['Unit'])  #2

df['Mass']=np.where(df['Unit']=='tn', df['Mass']*1000, df['Mass'])  #3
df['Unit']=np.where(df['Unit']=='tn', 'kg', df['Unit'])  #4
```

a) Is there a way to perform #1 & #2 in one line, maybe using `apply`?
b) Is it possible to perform #1, #2, #3 and #4 in only one line?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), BUT because numeric and string columns numeric values in `Mass` are converted to strings, so last step is converting to floats:

```
df['Mass'],df['Unit'] = np.select([df['Unit']=='g', df['Unit']=='tn'], 
                                [(df['Mass']/1000, np.repeat(['kg'], len(df))),
                                 (df['Mass']*1000, np.repeat(['kg'], len(df)))], 
                                (df['Mass'],df['Unit']))
df['Mass'] = df['Mass'].astype(float)
print (df)
    Mass Unit
0  0.014   kg
1  1.570   kg
2  0.701   kg
3  3.000   kg
4  0.600   kg
```

Same problem with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Mass'],df['Unit'] = np.where(df['Unit']=='g', 
                                (df['Mass']/1000, np.repeat(['kg'], len(df))), 
                                (df['Mass'],df['Unit']))
df['Mass'] = df['Mass'].astype(float)
print (df)
    Mass Unit
0  0.014   kg
1  1.570   kg
2  0.701   kg
3  0.003   tn
4  0.600   kg
```

Comment: Thanks, I like both solutions: I did not know that kind of operation such as taking both columns separately. I need to have a more thorough look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following which does not use any numpy functions,

```
(i,j) = (df[(df['Unit']=='g')].index, df[(df['Unit']=='tn')].index)    
df.loc[i,'Mass'], df.loc[j,'Mass'], df['Unit'] = df.loc[i,'Mass']/1000, df.loc[j,'Mass']*1000,'kg'
```